# Impossible to connect to a user at the MySQL CLI

Tags: mysql, sql, shell, command

I'm on this version of mysql :

> Server version: 8.0.20 MySQL Community Server - GPL

I just want to the user that i created. I do :

```
mysql -u USERNAME -p PASSWORD -h localhost;
```

And i get this generic error with no solution :

> ERROR 1064 (42000): You have an error in your SQL syntax; check the
>   manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version

Comment: *I just want to the user that i created. I do :* This command must be executed in shell command line (CMD for example), not in CLI. It starts CLI using specified MySQL account which must exist.

Comment: OK, but do I have to set an environment variable somewhere ? because cmd does not recognize 'mysql' as a command...

Comment: You may add the path where this executable is posessed to the system or user %PATH% variable. Or you may specify the path in the command. Or you may create some alias for this executable.

Comment: OK, do you have any links where i can refer to ?

Comment: https://superuser.com/questions/284342